Does exist a series which its ROC is $|z|=2$
The Problem
True or False: There's no series which its Z-transform ROC is exactly $|z| = 2$.
Book answer:
Consider the series: $$x[n] = \frac{2^n}{1+n^2}$$

The Z-transform of $x[n]$ is given by:

$$X(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{1+n^2} |z|^{-n}$$

Simplifying, it becomes:

$$X(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\left( 2|z|^{-1} \right)^n}{1+n^2}$$

This series converges iff $|z| = 2$ .

My Understanding
From my understanding, the ROC for a Z-transform must be a region (a ring) and cannot be a single value or contour. The ROC is defined as a range of $ z $-values for which the series converges, not a single value like $ |z| = 2 $. Thus, for any valid Z-transform, the ROC must be either:

$|z| > z_0$  (for a causal system)
$|z| < z_0$  (for an anti-causal system)
$z_0<|z|<z_1 $  (for a finite-duration sequence or a two-sided sequence)

Can anyone clarify if it's possible for a Z-transform to have an ROC of exactly $|z| = 2 $? How does the book's explanation fit with the formal definitions of ROC? Is there a way to justify a single-circle ROC within the framework of Z-transform theory?

To discuss "the formal definition of ROC", it would be prudent to have that definition in your Question.

I don't see why a particular contour can't be the values of $z$ for which the transform converges (which is what the ROC should be). I agree with the book example.

@Srini Thank you
